# Cómo usar autenticación tipo preemptive en un servicio web

Tags: vb.net, web, soap, autenticación, servicio

A ver si alguien me puede dar una pista de cómo usar una Authentication Type de tipo preemptive.

Yo creo que la petición que hago al servicio web es correcta salvo por ese detalle, ya que me devuelve "acceso denegado". Sé que los datos de usuario y contraseña son correctos porque al utilizar la aplicación SOAPUI puedo probarlo y me devuelve datos de prueba.

En el código tengo algo como esto:

```
Dim respuestaGet As RAEEResponse
Dim peticion As New getWasteEntriesChronologicalFileForSRARequest
Dim stub As New soapraeeClient()

With peticion
    .codSig = "01"
    .codCa = "14"        
    etc
End With

stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "usuario"
stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "clave"

respuestaGet = stub.getWasteEntriesChronologicalFileForSRA(peticion)
```

He omitido algunos fragmentos para verlo más fácil, pero respuestaGet se queda a Nothing y en la excepción que capturo me dice "Access Denied" pero en el SOAPUI sólo me dice eso si le quito el preemptive.

Como no encuentro por ningún lado cómo decirle que sea preemptive ¿alguien sabe cómo ponerlo? En el app.config (es una aplicación de escritorio quien consume el servicio) tampoco he visto que lo pueda indicar.

Comment: Mira [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1309f72a-5e95-47b9-89bf-60211a8a63e6/how-to-set-preemptive-authorization-when-using-service-reference-with-c?forum=wcf) (asumiendo que es un webservice WCF)

Comment: Hola. Lo del enlace que me has puesto parece funcionar. Ahora no devuelve "Acceso denegado" sino que respuestaGet se llena de información aunque dice "No se han encontrado resultados" y errCode 0200000001, pero eso ya será otra cosa. Gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegra que te haya servido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias nuevamente Pikoh, pues lo que me has dicho me ha funcionado.

Ya recibo datos y pongo la solución en formato Visual Basic .Net

```
Using (New ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(stub.InnerChannel))
    Dim auth As String = "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName & ":" & stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password))
    Dim requestMessage As ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty = New ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty()
    requestMessage.Headers("Authorization") = auth
    ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = requestMessage

    respuestaGet = stub.getWasteEntriesChronologicalFileForSRA(peticion)
End Using
```